# Instruments not detecting obvious memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I have created a very obvious memory leak in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]]];
temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]];
temp = nil;
```

However the tools show no memory leaks at any point, which leads me to believe there not working properly. Anybody else experienced this?

Comment: Do you ARC? If so, where is the leak? But even if not - you do not actually allocate any memory on heap. The only memory consumption there is on the stack for the local variable temp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my observation: the empty NSArray is basically a singleton instance. You can't create memory leaks in this way, because your app will always have a reference to the empty array "singleton".

This will show you that all empty arrays point to the same memory address:

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray array];
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array1];
NSArray *array3 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:@[]];
NSArray *array4 = @[];
NSArray *array5 = [@[] copy];
NSArray *array6 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]]];

NSLog(@"%p", array1);
NSLog(@"%p", array2);
NSLog(@"%p", array3);
NSLog(@"%p", array4);
NSLog(@"%p", array5);
NSLog(@"%p", array6);
```

No matter where in your application lifecycle you log the address of the empty array, it will always be the same.

You should try your test with `NSMutableArray`. Or, even better, use an class you created yourself.

Sometimes there is heavy optimization going on in the background if you use built in classes. For example class clusters, where you can't be sure what exact class an initializer returns, or singleton instances like in this case.